# Entry point of ASP.NET MVC app is not being reached. IIS issue?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I got a new laptop at work and, ever since then, I have not been able to run either of the MVC projects I'm assigned to. They build, I've deleted them completely and got the latest version from source control several times. I'm running Visual Studio Premium 2013. I had installed 2012 first but, once I ran out of ideas, I uninstalled both and reinstalled. I did make the following changes to the IIS applicationhost.config file (which are required for our apps because we use certificates, etc):

```
<iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true">
```

and

```
<access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
```

The other two developers working on these apps have been through the same procedures with their new laptops and they're not having problems. Here's what I get when I run my app in Chrome (won't let me post a screenshot cause I haven't earned any rep yet):

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

The connection to localhost was interrupted.

It basically goes instantly to this page. I have put a debugging stop in the Global.asax file at:

```
protected void Application_Start()
```

and it is never reached.

I've tried everything I can think of. A major problem is that I can't figure out what to even search for for a solution to this. I've Googled everything I can think of but the error is so vague and I'm not getting any exceptions. Please, please help. It's been going on more than a week. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled and reinstalled IIS Express 8.0 and everything worked. Don't know why I didn't try that before.